# When creating a node pool (multi-zone) with gcloud, the nodes do not register on the kubernetes master

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

When running the following `gcloud` command on my existing GKE cluster

```
SCOPES=(
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
)

gcloud beta container node-pools create $POOL_NAME \
--machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
--disk-size $DISK_SIZE \
--enable-autorepair \
--enable-autoscaling \
--min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 4 \
--cluster $CLUSTER \
--zone $ZONE \
--num-nodes 1 \
--scopes $(printf ",%s" "${SCOPES[@]}")
```

(Note this is regional, so using the beta command - I suspect this doesn't happen with non-regional clusters)
I get the following error:

```
    Creating node pool pool-alpha...done.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.container.node-pools.create) Operation [<Operation
 endTime: u'2018-03-29T08:56:14.989660264Z'
 name: u'operation-1522311735033-87b12027'
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(CREATE_NODE_POOL, 7)
 selfLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-d/operations/operation-1522311735033-87b12027'
 startTime: u'2018-03-29T08:22:15.03391313Z'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: u'All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered. Cluster may be unhealthy.'
 targetLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/xxxxxxxxxx/zones/europe-west1-d/clusters/digibet-prod/nodePools/pool-alpha'
 zone: u'europe-west1-d'>] finished with error: All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that only 0 nodes out of 3 have registered. Cluster may be unhealthy.
```

And indeed, the nodes are created but aren't registered on the cluster. A bug with GKE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your situation but looks like that is not a GKE issue.

I think the problem is in the `$(printf ",%s" "${SCOPES[@]}")` function, which creates a list starting from a comma, and it somehow affects available scopes.

I also found that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger` is not in the [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create) of available scopes for `node-pools create` command. But, based on Cloud Debugger [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/api/reference/rpc/google.devtools.clouddebugger.v2), you can use `cloud-platform` scope instead of `cloud_debugger`, and everything will be OK.

So, I checked the command with manually added scopes, it works fine:

```
gcloud beta container node-pools create $POOL_NAME \
--machine-type $MACHINE_TYPE \
--disk-size $DISK_SIZE \
--enable-autorepair \
--enable-autoscaling \
--min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 4 \
--cluster $CLUSTER \
--zone $ZONE \
--num-nodes 1 \
--scopes logging-write,monitoring-write,service-management,compute-rw,storage-rw,monitoring,pubsub,service-acontrol,service-management,sql-admin,trace,cloud-platform
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I've rectified my script and will let you know shortly how it goes - will be very happy if this works! :)

Comment: That was it - wow would have taken me forever to find the issue with the comma - so it does look like a bug in GKE/gcloud, but it is just very avoidable and probably non-consequential - thanks again for figuring that out for me